# insert into sqlserver with sqlParameters in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlparameter

```
void BtnConfirmClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string first = txtFname.Text;
   string last  = txtLname.Text;


   string query = "INSERT INTO customer (first, last)";
          query += " VALUES (@fstName,@lstName)";
   string url = "Server=localhost;Database=flight;uid=root;password=1234";

   con1 = new MySqlConnection(url);
   con1.Open();
   cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query,con1);

   //SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter("@fstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55);
   //myParam.Value = last;
   //SqlParameter myParam2 = new SqlParameter("@lstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55);
   //myParam2.Value = first;

   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fstName", first);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lstName", last);
   //cmd1.Parameters.Add(myParam);
   //cmd1.Parameters.Add(myParam2);

   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con1.Close();
}
```

I can't insert data into sqlServer, it keeps getting an error.
Please Help!!

Comment: Um, what is the error message?

Comment: "I can't insert data into sqlServer, it keeps getting an error" You might wan't to tell us what error?...

Comment: yes, please show us sql error you get... Insert in your code try {} catch block and exeprion message add to your original post

Comment: you want to insert data into sql server, but you use MySqlXXX, is that the problem?

Comment: Ok I got it guys, Thank you all anyway.

Comment: @Praetor12 Thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: If you found your problem, answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ar the first glance you have forgot about ending char (; in your sql query). You need:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO customer (first, last)";
       query += " VALUES (@fstName,@lstName);";
```